# Wifi, VPN and IP addresses

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, ip

I am connecting to a set of VPN servers using wifi on my Macbook Air. I am trying to understand the triangle of relationships between the wifi connection (provided by my ISP), the connections to the VPN servers (a set of 16 worldwide servers that I can connect to using a subscription to a proprietary VPN application) and the external IP address that is associated with my connection.

Could someone please explain the sequence of low-level networking events that occurs when I

1. connect to the wifi
2. connect to the VPN server and
3. browse the web?

When I'm connected to the wifi, without connecting to a VPN server, I see two IP addresses, one is `198.168.0.4` which I think is my router's IP address on the ISP's network (internal), and the other is `2.216.180.116` which is the (external) IP address on on the internet of the ISP host that handles the connection.

Am I right? I was told that the command `ipconfig getifaddr en1` on Terminal would return the external address, but it doesn't display anything. The command `ipconfig getifaddr en0` just displays the internal address.

When I connect to a VPN server, say the one in Singapore then the external address changes to that server's address. Is there a way of getting this from Terminal?

I started using the VPN service because of the promise of privacy and security but it appears that NSA and other intelligence agencies are able to target specific VPN servers? Is there any way of hiding your local address even if the VPN server was compromised?

Sorry for any errors or misunderstandings, I am a newbie to networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do much more reading on the "low level" aspect. Read up the OSI model.

1. Your ISP provided modem dials up to connect you to the Internet. You get assigned a "public IP".
2. Because the number of IPv4 addresses are limited and people want to connect multiple devices to "share" an Internet connection a device called a "router" creates a smaller network using a different set of IPs. It uses NAT to convert your internal requests bound for the Internet to use your public IP. The internal IPs can be re-used throughout routers around the world as they will always remain "hidden" from the Internet. My explanation is simplified because networking is vast and you should read up.
3. WiFi and Ethernet are simply two different networking mediums - they are "physical layers" of the OSI model. The data they carry is still the same, they just use different hardware that must overcome the "wired" and "wireless".
4. A VPN is a method to create a "tunnel" over a WAN (mostly the "Internet"). When you connect to a VPN your computer still uses your ISP public IP as this will always be required to use the connection; but as a VPN is a tunnel it allows your computer to connect to a remote network and obtain another Internal IP much like the one your router gives your laptop. Your laptop can then use your office resources like remote desktop, printers, shared drives etc that would otherwise be inaccessible over the Internet as they, too, will have internal IPs (and firewalls etc) that are hidden by your company "routers" (simplified because corporate networks can be extremely complicated). VPN servers are "open to the Internet" through open ports and routes through firewalls (they have to be too enable you to connect in) but  if the servers are managed correctly and the tunnel data is encrypted well enough then whatever data is sent over the VPN will be unobtainable. If your company is big enough then they will have thought about all this on your behalf...
5. To obtain your "public" IP from within your LAN isn't very easy because, technically, your LAN never needs to know it. This is the router's job. When you request data from addresses it cannot resolve locally (within your LAN) it hands it off to its "default gateway" (your modem) to see if it can provide the data you've requested. The modem then communicates with your ISP to see if it can fulfil the request. You can see how networks simply "hand it off" to other devices - hence you'll never need to know your public IP. If you want to know your public IP then you can log on to your modem/router where it will (most times) tell you what IP it has been given or you can Google "what is my IP" and it will return the address of your ISP connection IP.

I've simplified the steps above but this is the basics of what you've asked.

Comment: I upvoted, but will add that there are other uses for VPN's.  The "tunnel" is an encrypted path. One popular use is connecting to/browsing the internet over the tunnel, where at that point your isp assigned external IP is hidden from the servers you are connecting to making it very hard to trace, or perhaps gives you access to sites that wouldn't be available in your country of origin.

Comment: Cheers for the additional info Tyson. I was unsure whether to add that because the OP didn't seem to be asking. Well, they mentioned about how to obtain their public IP but I think they're trying to obtain their own public IP from a device on the VPN. This wouldn't work unless they had access to the VPN server...

Comment: I didn't think the OPs use case was the office network across town, a couple references in the question make me suspect this might be more the usage case.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, it's helpful.  I'm reading stuff on TCP/IP and network to help me understand better.  I am talking about connecting from home, not from an office.  I may have more questions in a few days and will post here if that's OK.